# Should I put my mortgage in deferment?

Tags: united-states, mortgage, credit-report, credit-history, home-loan

Times have been rough! I lost my job and despite interviewing I have only been ghosted by recruiters and companies. I have started offering tech/software consulting services but given I am new to the consulting side of things, I don't have clients.

As it happens, we're very close to depleting 6-months of buffer that we have for mortgage because there are living expenses as well.

I have called my bank and they have 2 options to defer mortgage. It seems that in some way it will show up on a credit report (which is 740+ right now) as 'deferred'? Is this going to be serious in the short/long term? I can arrange to pay off the deferred amount when I get a job or at least in some months when I sell an investment property.

The options are:

1. Add the deferred payments to the monthly mortgages until the end of the mortgage
2. Refinance/recalculate the mortgage terms (not going to pick this)
3. Pay a lumpsum equal to the deferred amount within a month of resuming payments.

All these can be done month-to-month.
*The bank said the option to apply to defer is a fairly easy process. I want to make sure I consider the ramifications before deciding which way to go.*

Comment: Are you still seriously and actively looking for a job or are you trying to offer consulting services?  You cannot successfully do both at the same time.  If you are committed to consulting prepare to lose money for the next 2 years, in which case you should not try to defer your mortgage as you are just delaying the inevitable.  If you have been looking for a job seriously for 6 months and haven't found one yet it's not looking great on that front either unfortunately.

Comment: @jesse_b I read recently that, on average, about 30% of the workforce changes jobs per year, so millions of people with full-time jobs successfully job-hunt, of course someone can do both things. Also, I don't see any reason why they'd expect to lose money, tech consulting work can have almost no overhead, there are gig-sites for tech workers that make it easy to bring in a little something on the side if desired.

Comment: @HartCO For every one person that succeeds in consulting there are probably 99 that fail.   It's no different from starting a business, you should **plan** for the first 1-2 years to be a loss, if you gain money in that time good but don't *plan* on it.   If you land a consulting contract and then secure a job you cannot do both at the same time so you either have to breach your contract or turn the job down.

Comment: Also in my experience most consultants are just temporary employees that don't have health insurance.

Comment: @jesse_b Not all contracts/jobs prevent you from engaging in other work, I'd argue most don't, but some of that varies significantly by state labor laws. Temporary work for temporary income while hunting another job is very reasonable.

Comment: @HartCO a full time position explicitly preventing you from engaging in other work is the norm but even if it's not a contractual obligation it's just impractical from a time management standpoint.

Answer (score 2):

I'd never heard of mortgage deferment, so some of this is assumptions. But:

I presume there are costs associated with it, presumably adding interest for the time it is deferred and possibly increasing the interest rate since you're less reliable than they had hoped. Either would mean either higher payments or additional years of payment on top of the ones you skipped.

Get the actual numbers before deciding whether this really makes sense.

Of course your alternative is selling the house, paying off the loan, finding housing that you can afford, and buying upscale again when your finances can actually cover the mortgage payments. Run numbers on that too. You'll do better selling voluntarily than if the house is repossessed, certainly.

---

The added details are helpful, but don't change my basic answer: whatever you choose, make sure you are going to be able to afford it when you come out of it. The option you said you've rejected (recalculating the amortization) is the only one which might let you resume without either a surcharge or an increase in your monthly payments, so you need to be sure that your income will be high enough to either handle the additional costs.

Of course the refinance option would add more time before you're paid off, more total cost for that reason, and might (depending on what they offer you) be at a different interest rate (check!), all of which are also legitimate concerns.

Basically, be very aware that there's no free lunch here. You really are just kicking the can down the road a bit; you are going to have to pick it up later, and the bank will charge interest for this additional time so there is a real cost.

Comment: I'll add the details to the question as edits but there are flexible options. Selling the house is a much bigger overhead to be honest. With the optimism of eventually getting back onto the job/contract market I wanted to understand the long term impacts of this 'deferred' entry that I am imagining on the credit report.